# How to set list of values present in pandas dataframe, based on groupby key?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, psycopg2

I am using pandas.dataframe in python code to find total pending_count & list of ticket_ids for a priority (based on priority) as below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'priority': priority,
                   'pending_count': pending_count,
                   'ticket_id':ticket_id})
```

I am able to find the total Pending_count for a priority but now, I need to find the list of ticket_id for that priority.

To get the total sum of pending_count for a priority, I am doing below :

```
for i, v in df.groupby(['priority'])['priority'].count().items():

     total_incident = {
                    "priority": i
                    
                    }
     for priority, pending_count in df.groupby(['priority'])['pending_count'].sum().items(): 
            if priority == i:
                        total_incident["pending_count"] = pending_count
```

The above code is working fine for setting total pending_count. Now, I would like to set list of ticket_id for that priority, something as below.

```
total_incident["ticket_id"] = [101, 201, 303, ...]
```

I would appreciate , if someone helps with the python syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can try using `groupby` with `.agg`

Remember to import numpy as np, instead of `sum()`, we use `np.sum`

```
for priority, pending_count in df.groupby(['priority']).agg({'pending_count': np.sum, "ticket_id" : lambda x: list(pd.unique(x))}) 
            if priority == i:
                        total_incident["pending_count"] = pending_count
```